# A little complex criteria query for entities with a many-to-many relation

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have 2 entities, `role` and `permission`. They are linked with a many-to-many relation. I want to find all permissions that are **not** assigned to a specific role using the criteria API. The permissions could be assigned to other roles or not assigned at all.

What I came up with is the following:

```
    Specification<Permission> specification = (permission, query, cb) -> cb.not(permission.join(Permission_.roles).get(Role_.id).in(roleId));
    specification = specification.or((permission, query, cb) -> cb.isEmpty(permission.get(Permission_.roles)));
```

This generates the following query (replaced all columns with *):

```
select permission0_.*
from permission permission0_ 
inner join role2permission roles1_ on permission0_.id=roles1_.permission_id 
inner join role role2_ on roles1_.role_id=role2_.id 
where role2_.id not in (?) or  not (exists (select role4_.id 
                                        from role2permission roles3_, role role4_ 
                                        where permission0_.id=roles3_.permission_id 
                                        and roles3_.role_id=role4_.id))
```

But it does not work correctly. Is there something I have missed ?

Comment: See [mcve]. "does not work correctly" isnt a proper problem description. What happens, and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
Specification<Permission> specification = (permission, query, cb) -> cb.isMember(role, permission.get(Permission_.roles)).not();
specification = specification.or((permission, query, cb) -> cb.isEmpty(permission.get(Permission_.roles)));
```

use a Role object instead of roleId